# how to write bash script to read from a text file and filter based on nth read line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

i have this text file

```
Zipcode:123
ExpectedAge:24
ActualAge:26
Zipcode:12333
ExpectedAge:21
ActualAge:24
...
...
```

I am trying to write a script to compare Expected and Actual age for a zipcode and print that.

**output rule**

> print the zipcodes for which expectedage > actualAge

Is bash/sed/awk is a good idea to achieve this.

Comment: what output do you want

Comment: print the zipcode for which expectedage > actualAge

Comment: No, don't **describe** the output - edit your question to specifically **SHOW** what the output would be given the sample input file you posted. And yes, awk is the right tool for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to use modulus operator,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} 
     {d[$1]=$2} 
     !(NR%3) && d["ExpectedAge"]>d["ActualAge"]{
         print d["Zipcode"];
     }' file
```

Comment: i have to only print the zipcode for which expected age is greater than actual age. Also could you explain the script a bit in detail.

Comment: @jigsaw ..... not much to explain, just I use the modulus operator (mean: each three lines)